# Smart contract to send ERC20 token from one address to another

Tags: blockchain, solidity, erc20

I'm trying to implement a Solidity smart contract that will send deployed tokens from address A to address B.

Address A - should be the current user calling the contract function "stake".
Address B - should be a custom wallet address from outside.

```
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";

contract TokenTransfer {
    IERC20 _token;

    constructor(address token) public {
        _token = IERC20(token);
    }

    function stake(address to, uint amount) public {
        _token.approve(address(this), amount);
        require(_token.allowance(msg.sender, address(this)) >= amount, "Token allowance too low");
        bool sent = _token.transferFrom(msg.sender, to, amount);
        require(sent, "Token transfer failed");
    }
}
```

Current implementation returns allowance error:
"Token allowance too low"

I'm running it with MetaMask (injected web3). I expected MetaMask to open a simple transfer window with my token.

Answer (score 2):

In order to use `transferFrom()` from your contract, the token holder needs to `approve()` the spender (your contract) directly from their address. Not through your contract.

---

```
_token.approve(address(this), amount);
```

This snippet approves `TokenTransfer` (`address(this)`) to spend `TokenTransfer`'s (the `approve()` function invoker) tokens, because the function is effectively invoked from the `TokenTransfer`'s address.

That's why the `require()` condition is failing. The token holder (`msg.sender`) hasn't approved your contract (`address(this)`) to spend their tokens. If you replaced the condition to `_token.allowance(address(this), address(this))`, then it would pass (see the previous paragraph).

Answer (score 0):

The staker calling the method needs to call `approve` himself. This is because `approve` gives an allowance of tokens from `msg.sender` to another address, as so:

```
approve(address spender, uint256 amount)
```

The `msg.sender` in the approve call, as it is in your code, is the  `TokenTransfer` contract itself, with it calling the `allowance` method of `_token`.

This means that, instead of the staker giving an allowance to the `TokenTransfer` contract, as they are not `msg.sender` during the `approve` call, the `TokenTransfer` contract is giving an allowance to itself.

In addition to this, I would also recommend in general using `increaseAllowance` and `decreaseAllowance` to give allowances to addresses. See `IERC20` `approve` issues at https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/api/token/erc20 for more information.