# How exactly do i faciliate a transaction of an established ERC20 token between two users?

Tags: solidity, remix, erc20

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

```
import 'Token.sol';
import 'Encap.sol';

contract HEX_Extension  {


function transfer_addy(address _to, uint amount) external {{
    IHEX(0x2b591e99afE9f32eAA6214f7B7629768c40Eeb39).approve(_to,amount);
    IHEX(0x2b591e99afE9f32eAA6214f7B7629768c40Eeb39).transferFrom(msg.sender,_to,amount);
}}
}
```

I am writing a contract that extends the functionality of HEX, an ERC20 token. I cannot for the life of me figure out how to validate a transaction between two users. Can someone explain what's wrong with this code? I keep getting thrown the error that says the allowance is too low, even though i set the allowance in the transfer method.

I'm not sure if this makes a difference, but I am testing this contract in the Injected Web3 setting in Remix.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Smart contract to send ERC20 token from one address to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70516046/smart-contract-to-send-erc20-token-from-one-address-to-another)

Comment: It's definitely the same problem I'm having, but I'm still not understanding exactly how to fix it. I ended up figuring out that i need to grant approval to the contract, but I don't know how to do that from msg.sender. From what I gather, I'm calling the 'approve' method on my contract, from my contract. Any ideas how to have an external account do this?

Comment: The end user needs to call the `approve()` method on the `0x2b591...` contract - the same way as they're calling the `transfer_addy()` method on your contract.

Answer (score 0):

This line doesn't not allows the `HEX` to use your token on behalf of `HEX_Extension` as you might expected.

```
IHEX(0x2b591e99afE9f32eAA6214f7B7629768c40Eeb39).approve(_to,amount);
```

You need to make an approval from your wallet to the `IHEX`, that allows he address of contract `HEX_Extension` use your own token.

---

Example: let's say you deployed the `HEX_Extension` into address `0xABCDE...`. Then from your MM, make a call to approve function of `HEX` contract, `approve(0xABCDE...., amount)` before the `transfer_addy`.